# Display the current page's hash/anchor in the page's body with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, anchor

Say a user visits the page http://somedomain.com/path/file.html#foo, I'd like to display, using JavaScript, somewhere on the page a text like:

```
 → foo
```

Comment: You mean you own the page and want that behavior for every user, or you want a browser extension to do something like that?

Comment: I own the page and would like it to display whatever is after the #

Comment: ok. Then see my answer I took the liberty to rewrite your question a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `window.location.hash` to grab the anchor's name.

   ```
   var anchorName = window.location.hash;
   ```
2. Create a text node to display what you want:

   ```
   var path = document.createTextNode("→ " + anchorName);
   ```
3. Add it to the Dom:

   ```
   document.getElementById(idOfContainerYouWantToEdit).appendChild(path);
   ```